# Why jQuery next can't find the next div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, find, jquery-selectors, element

I want to create a page for FAQs and used jQuery to show each answer. But it does not work.
The format of each question-answer is like this:

```
<div><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="expand">First Question</a></div>
<div class="answer" style="display:none">First Answer</div>
```

And the jQuery code that I have used is:

```
$(".expand").click(function(){
    $(this).next('.answer').slideToggle();
});
```

Is it wrong? You can see its [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p3sFh/1/) too.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The two elements are not at the same level for `next()` to work.

Try this:

```
$(".expand").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().next('.answer').slideToggle();
});
```

Here is an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p3sFh/2/) for your reference

Comment: How to use selectors for this - http://jsfiddle.net/8HH9L/4/ I want to hide selected rows in table after the button...

Answer (score 3):

Because `jQuery.next()` grabs siblings, the div you're trying to get is the parent's sibling, not the sibling.

Answer (score 2):

Well $(this) is the a-element, and there are no siblings to that element. If you want the div, use parent:

```
$(this).parent().next()
```